# How to convert variable from java to php?

Tags: php

I'm creating player panel for my friend in php, but I have problem with variable shown below. I must insert into variable in php, and send request to database. What is my problem? I can't convert java code, because I don't know how I can do this. It may be strange, but unfortunately it is.

I tried do this with amateur way, using;
    require 'mojang-api.class.php';

```
$uuid = MojangAPI::getUuid('jeb_');
echo 'UUID: <b>' . $uuid . '</b><br>';
echo substr($uuid, 0, 8); echo '-'; echo substr($uuid, 8, 12); echo '-'; substr($uuid, 13, 15); echo '-';
```

but, You and I know this - this way sucks.

I place the java code below.

Java:

```
uuid.substring(0, 8) + '-' + uuid.substring(8, 12) + '-' + uuid.substring(12, 16) + '-' + uuid.substring(16, 20) + '-' + uuid.substring(20)
```

If someone can help me with this problem, I'll be grateful.

Comment: You forgot to explain your problem.

Comment: Edited; What is my problem? I can't convert java code, because I don't know how I can do this. It may be strange, but unfortunately it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

```
$uuid = MojangAPI::getUuid('jeb_');
echo 'UUID: <b>' . $uuid . '</b><br>';
echo substr($uuid, 0, 8).'-'.substr($uuid, 8, 4).'-'.substr($uuid, 13, 2);
```

Instead of plus + in Java you use the dot . in PHP. Amazingly you used it in the line above?

Comment: By this code, uuid has been extended from 32 characters to 68, wow. I do not know what is wrong, but it seems to me substr is repeated somewhere. Everything looks correct.

Comment: Sorry, `substr(start, len)` not `substr(start, end)` - I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot about this. <3